# Checkbox for terms and conditions, without column in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a "I accept terms of service" checkbox on a page, it has to be checked in order for the order to proceed. It seems hence illogical to have a column in the database to match this (whether user has accepted or declined terms).

I am using the form helper like this in my view:

```
<%= check_box("client", "terms") %>
```

And in my model:

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms
```

At the moment it is not working at all.

This seems like a really common piece of code, yet I can't find it used anywhere without having the terms in the model. Else I could use javascript to validate it, but would prefer to keep it all the in model.

Comment: Javascript can be turned off so you cant just rely on that to validate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work fine, without a database column or attr_accessor:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance

I would be inclined to check your params hash is as it should be i.e. that the 'terms' attribute is being passed within the 'client' hash, perhaps try adding `raise params.inspect` on your controller create action to help you debug?

Comment: Cheers, this worked great - and I learnt a bit about degbugging!

Comment: The Link to the Rails Guide is Broken

Comment: Current rails uses a [slightly different format](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#acceptance): `validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true`

Answer (score 6):

What about having an `attr_accessor :terms` in your Client model?

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me as I didn't include it in my attr_accessor, thus it did not get passed through for validation.

Answer (score 3):

I had this working with these settings:

In the `controller`, I have added :terms_of_service as a permitted field:

```
def application_params
  params.require(:application).permit(. . . , :terms_of_service)
end
```

In the `model`:

```
attr_accessor :terms_of_service
validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true
```

In the `view`:

```
<%= f.check_box("terms_of_service", :checked => false) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

attr_accessor :terms will do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Either go with @neutrino's solution, or to reset :terms to "not accepted" if you need to redisplay the form (because validation may fail), use this:

```
def terms
  nil
end

def terms=(val)
  # do nothing
end
```